# How do I initialize an Model object in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a website where I want every user to start off with certain values for their attributes.

Here is the class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, 
              :email, 
              :goal, 
              :measurement, 
              :bmr_formula, 
              :fat_factor, 
              :protien_factor

end
```

In rails console --sandbox I'm able to change the values. But I want to start the object off with certain values.

For example, I want measurement to begin with "US", bmr_formula to begin with "Katch"...etc instead of nil.

right now, everything starts with nil.

I'll proceed to show what I've tried with the results each attempt got.

---

---

**Here is what worked:**

```
after_initialize do 
   self[:measurement] = "US" 
   self[:bmr_formula] = "katch"
   self[:fat_factor] = 0.655
   self[:protein_factor] = 1.25
   puts "User has been initialized!"
end


1.9.3p125 :001 > user = User.new
User has been initialized!
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, goal: nil, measurement: "US", bmr_formula: 
"katch", fat_factor: 0, protein_factor: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p125 :002 >
```

**Thanks for the help everyone!**

---

---

Full Class:

```
attr_accessible :name, 
              :email, 
              :goal, 
              :measurement, 
              :bmr_formula, 
              :fat_factor, 
              :protien_factor


def initialize(measurement)                
@measurement = measurement
# bmr_formula = "katch"
# fat_factor = 0.655
# protien_factor = 1.25
  end
```

Console:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > user = User.new("US")
 => #<User not initialized>
```

---

Bottom of Class:

```
 def initialize               
    @measurement = "US"
    # bmr_formula = "katch"
    # fat_factor = 0.655
    # protien_factor = 1.25
  end
```

Console:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > user = User.new
 => #<User not initialized> 
1.9.3p125 :002 >
```

---

Bottom of Class:

```
self.@measurement = "US"
```

Console:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/Nick/Code/Rails/fitness_app/app/models/user.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR
self.@measurement = "US"
```

---

Class:

```
after_initialize :measurement, 
                 :bmr_formula, 
                 :fat_factor, 
                 :protien_factor

 def defaults
   self.measurement = "US"
   self.bmr_formula = "katch"
   self.fat_factor = 0.655
   self.protien_factor = 1.25
  end
```

Console:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > user = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, goal: nil, measurement: nil, bmr_formula:    
nil, fat_factor: nil, protien_factor: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3p125 :002 > user.measurement
=> nil 
1.9.3p125 :003 > user.bmr_formula
=> nil
```

Comment: Besides using dominic answer below, if you put defaults on your migrations (database tables) rails will use those. Or if using new User.new(:measurement => "US"), Pass a hash

Comment: I think I'm writing these wrong because I just got it to work with before_create. It didn't show that the values changed until I did a user.inspect, and saw that, the values were indeed correct and not nil.

Comment: just to be clear, using `before_create` will work when inserting the model into the database, not when binding it to a view `User.new(: measurement => "US")` vs `User.create!(:measurement => "FOO")` depending on what your before_create looks like it might overwrite FOO? User.new could be used on a view so the user saw the value US in the input field

Comment: I want those values to be saved to the database immediately.

Comment: before_create only works when I call the object for that particular attribute. That's interesting.

Comment: not sure what you mean? `before_create` should be called when you call `create` or `create!`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15304/discussion-between-house9-and-ninja08)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the `after_initialize` callback:

```
after_initialize :default_values
def default_values
  self.status ||= 'P'
  self.measurement = "US"
  self.bmr_formula = "katch"
  self.fat_factor = 0.655
  self.protien_factor = 1.25
end
```

Comment: Haven't been able to get it to work with this. It's returning all the values as nil.

Comment: I added the results on the end of my original question. I may have written it wrong.

Comment: I think the answer should be `def default_values` for the callback to be referenced correctly.

Comment: I edited the question to include exact what I did to get it to work. I had to tinker around with this get it right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use before_create to get in there and muck with things before the object is saved for the first time. If you need it before you've ever saved it, you can use before_initialize to accomplish something similar.

You'd also just want to set self.measurement, not self.@measurement.

Comment: Yea I caught the last bit you mentioned. 

I've tried the before_create, and the before_initialize. There are no error messages, but all the values are still nil when console shows me what happened.

Comment: I think the guy below me has the right idea, after_initialize!