# Ruby: Class.new gives "Class not initialized" error in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a lightweight app to create and display information for upcoming events. I have an Event class defined that takes an args hash as a parameter. The initialize method is defined below.

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  def initialize(args={})
    @what       = args[:what]
    @theme      = args[:theme]
    ... 
  end
end
```

So far, so good. Then, in Rails Console, I define an args hash and try to create an instance of Event but get the following error.

```
[4] pry(main)> args = {what: 'what', theme: 'theme'}
=> {:what=>"what", :theme=>"theme"}
[5] pry(main)> Event.new(args)
=> #<Event not initialized>
```

This seems really straightforward but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945070/how-do-i-initialize-an-model-object-in-ror

Comment: No, I don't need default initial values for the class. The AR answer below was the one that I was looking for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to do a `def initialize` block for ActiveRecord-inheriting classes, you have to call `super(args)` inside this block in order for the subclass to be properly initialised.

However, if `what` and `theme` already exists as columns in your model, you don't need the initialize method: `Event.new(args)` will work fine out of the box.

A good practice would be to only use `initialize` block when you need to define variables that are not present in your ActiveRecord schema (e.g. setting instance variables that do not need persistence), but if you need to do that then it's the more common practice to use `attr_accessor`.

Comment: That makes sense. I knew I was missing something simple. That said, it would be good if the error message was more descriptive.

Comment: Half of this answer is false. You indeed CAN do a `def initialize` on an AR-inheriting class; however you will need to call `super(args)` in the initialize block in order for the child class to be initialized properly. Steve is right regarding the columns, if they exist already no need to bother with an `initialize` block.

Comment: @JordanBecker good point, thanks for the edit.  I've approved and added clarification about using `attr_accessor` as an alternative.

Comment: You're very welcome, glad you brought up the `attr_accessor` as well!

Comment: For calling `super`, no `args` necessary, right? Any arguments are passed to `super` automagically, no?

Comment: @ilasno that's right, although if you explicity specify arguments, they're used instead.  Doing `super()` will pass with no arguments.