# simple_form_for does not seem to update record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form-for

I am relatively new to rails.  This must be a very basic question but I am unable to find an answer.

My problem: pressing submit does not seem to update my record.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@select_statement) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'form_error', f:f %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title, :label => 'Required: Short title for this sql SELECT statment' %>
    <%= f.input :description, required: false,  :label => 'Optional: Long description of your sql SELECT statment' %>
    <%= f.input :sql_select_statement, :label => 'Required: Your sql SELECT statment' %>
    <%= f.input :user_email %>
    <%= f.input :favorite, :input_html => { :checked => false } %>

      <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here's my .rb file

```
class RalphValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xyz = 123
  end
end

class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    # byebug if ralph_test_byebug

    email_regex = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
    record.errors[:base] << 'email address missing or invalid!!!  Internal system error!!!' unless record.user_email =~ email_regex
    # record.errors[:base] << 'surface mail address missing!!!' unless record.user_email =~ email_regex
    # xyz=123
    # record.errors.add :user_email, 'email address missing!!!' unless record.user_email =~ email_regex
  end
end


class SelectStatement < ActiveRecord::Base
  # See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :user_email

  before_validation(on: :create) do
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xyz = 123
  end


  validates_with RalphValidator

  validates :sql_select_statement, presence: true
  # validates :user_email, presence: true, email: true
  validates :favorite, inclusion: [true, false]
  byebug if ralph_test_byebug
  validates_with EmailValidator, fields: [:user_email]

  # see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2220311&seqNum=2
  before_save :ralph_before_save

  def ralph_before_save
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xyz=123
  end


  if true
    def initialize(args)
      byebug if ralph_test_byebug

      # See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050181/ruby-class-new-gives-class-not-initialized-error-in-rails-console
      super

      byebug if ralph_test_byebug

      @initialize_args = args           # May be unnecessary
      @user_email = args[:user_email]   # Probably unnecessary

      byebug if ralph_test_byebug
      xyz=123
    end
  end

  if true
    # See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find

    after_initialize do |s_hash|
      zyx = new_record?

      byebug if ralph_test_byebug

      s_hash[:user_email] = @user_email

      byebug if ralph_test_byebug
      # xyz=123
    end
  end
end
```

And now app/controllers/select_statements_controller.rb

```
class SelectStatementsController < DeviseApplicationController
  before_action :set_select_statement, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /select_statements
  # GET /select_statements.json
  def index
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    @select_statements = SelectStatement.all
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xxx=123
  end

  # GET /select_statements/1
  # GET /select_statements/1.json
  def show
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xxx=123
  end

  # GET /select_statements/new
  def new
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    @select_statement = SelectStatement.new({user_email:@current_user})

    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xyz=123
  end

  # GET /select_statements/1/edit
  def edit
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xxx=123
  end

  # POST /select_statements
  # POST /select_statements.json
  def create
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    # byebug if ralph_test_byebug

    # @select_statement = SelectStatement.new(select_statement_params:select_statement_params)
    # @select_statement = SelectStatement.new({user_email:@current_user, select_statement_params:select_statement_params})
    @select_statement = SelectStatement.new({user_email:@current_user})

    byebug if ralph_test_byebug

    respond_to do |format|
      if @select_statement.save
        format.html { redirect_to @select_statement, notice: 'Select statement was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @select_statement }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @select_statement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /select_statements/1
  # PATCH/PUT /select_statements/1.json
  def update
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug
    xxx=123

    respond_to do |format|
      if @select_statement.update(select_statement_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @select_statement, notice: 'Select statement was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @select_statement }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @select_statement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /select_statements/1
  # DELETE /select_statements/1.json
  def destroy
    @here = s_here(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    byebug if ralph_test_byebug

    @select_statement.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to select_statements_url, notice: 'Select statement was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_select_statement
      byebug if ralph_test_byebug

      @select_statement = SelectStatement.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def select_statement_params
      # byebug if ralph_test_byebug

      params.require(:select_statement).permit(:title, :description, :sql_select_statement, :user_email, :favorite)
    end
end
```

My basic question: Where does Rails insert the fields of the form into the record?  I have tried, for instance, before_validate, validates_with, before_save, ...

Every time I hit a byebug breakpoint in the code above - except for the attribute associated with :user_email - self or @select_statement is just full of nils.

Obviously, I'm missing something very basic.

Comment: Can you please share your controller file

Comment: Oh wow.  It's amazing how just asking a question can focus the mind and make you look in a different place.

OK, I looked at params at entry to **create**  and I get `{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx==", "select_statement"=>{"title"=>"", "description"=>"", "sql_select_statement"=>"abcd;", "favorite"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Select statement", "controller"=>"select_statements", "action"=>"create"}`
which is correct.

Yet
`@select_statement = SelectStatement.new({user_email:@current_user})` does not merge in params.

Do I have to do the merge manually?  (I added the controller.)

Answer (score 0):

So, much to my amazement, Rails 4 added a whole new security feature: Strong Parameters.

It appears that the behavior I was expecting - row attributes would be filled in automatically - is no longer true in Rails 4 and that row/record assignment must be handled manually.

I found a good jumping off point for learning about Strong Parameters is:
http://blog.trackets.com/2013/08/17/strong-parameters-by-example.html

This is my noob belief.  I welcome comments and correction.